# Zxing issue - ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, zxing

I am getting an `Exception` while working with `zxing` scanner. In my application, I want to scan `Bar` and `QR` codes by single-camera `Activity` ( `CaptureActivity` of zxing). For that, I used the following code in my app

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
              intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
              startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But I am getting the exception:-

```
01-03 10:28:15.445: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
{ act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
```

I can't use

```
  IntentIntegrator
```

in my App. So please someone help me, to solve this issue.
This is my full log cat output

```
             01-04 04:58:39.551: D/AndroidRuntime(905): Shutting down VM
                     01-04 04:58:39.551: W/dalvikvm(905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
                      01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) }
                       01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
                       01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
                     01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
                     01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
                      01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at com.google.zxing.shopping.shopping$1.onClick(shopping.java:98)
                          01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                      01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                         01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                         01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                              01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                           01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                          01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                        01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                       01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                              01-04 04:58:39.581: E/AndroidRuntime(905):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting ActivityNotFoundException as Zxing application is not installed in your device. So Please check whether it is installed or not. If it's not then redirect user to playstore-page of Zxing:

I've implemented some code for these. Modify it according to your needs:

```
boolean isZxingInstalled;
/*
 *Checking whether Zxing is installed or not
 */ 
try
{
ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.zxing.client.android", 0 );
boolean isZxingInstalled = true;
    }
catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
                isZxingInstalled=false;
          }

/*
 * Store the boolean value on the basis of Zxing is installed or not
 */

if(isZxingInstalled) //If it is then intent Zxing application
 {
         //start the facebook app
         Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
          intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS",    "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
  }
 else //It's not then redirect user to PlayStore-ZxingPlage
  {
    /*
     *Checking whether PlayStore is installed in device or not?
     */
     boolean isPlayStoreInstalled
     try
     {
      ApplicationInfo i=getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.vending", 0 );
      boolean isPlayStoreInstalled = true;
      }
     catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
                isPlayStoreInstalled=false;
          }

      /*
       * If it is the download Zxing
       */ 
      if(isPlayStoreInstalled)
       {
        Intent DownloadZxing = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://detailsid=com.google.zxing.client.android"));
        startActivity(DownloadZxing);
        }
      else //Toast message indicating No PlayStore Found
       {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Install PlayStore First",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
        }
  }
```

Hope these may help!! :)

Comment: @Patel ..is it possible to scan qr & bar code  without using third party App.? I just did copy paste of all zxing package in my project. Thanks for your response. I please help me

Comment: @ That means i am asking without installing any other App.

Comment: @Artyom.. How it is possible ?? I am new in android world.So please help me..I will really thankful for your great help....

Comment: I prefer this method to know if the Zxing is on the device:    private boolean isZxingInstalledOnDevice(){    
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");    
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");    
        ResolveInfo info=getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );    
        //then if info!=null, the Intent can be launched, else the package is not installed    
        return info!=null;    
    }